# how to convert audio CMSampleBufferRef to data, and play the audio in other device with data received

Tags: ios, audio, cmsamplebufferref

I try to implement a video conference, i can capture video and audio with CaputreSession, and covert video CMSampleBufferRef to image and send data to other device.

But i don't have any idea how i can convert audio CMSampleBufferRef to data, and play audio in other device with data?

Some one can help me, please?

Edit:

I have find [this](http://blog.csdn.net/zxc110110/article/details/7188092) in a chinese website, it say we can read data in CMSamplerBufferRef with OpenAL. I have try the code in my project, it seems OpenAL and AvCaptureSession with audio can not work together, because OpenAL with a file works just fun. some one can help me  with that?????

Comment: I am also facing same problem now. Do you got solution for this?

Comment: Does anybody found a solution for this?